# intent-filter in manifest file to enable the open button on install

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin.android

I am fairly new to Android Development and I have seen examples where this is put into the Manifest.xml file:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />`
</intent-filter>
```

I thought this was what I needed so that after my Application Installs the open button would be enabled.  However, even though Ihave this in my Manifest the button is stlll disabled.

So, can anyone tell me ehat I am doing wrong?

Thanks for any help.

** UPDATE...

Here is my full Manifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" 
            android:versionName="1.1" package="com.MyAppName.app">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" targetSdkVersion="10" />

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />

    <permission android:name="com.MyAppName.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <permission android:name="com.MyAppName.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.MyAppName.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.MyAppName.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <application android:label="@string/MyAppName" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:icon="@drawable/Icon">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="MY_KEY" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

** UPDATE

Here is the code for the activity:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;

namespace MyApp
{
    [Activity (Label = "MyApp", MainLauncher = true, Theme="@style/Theme.Splash", NoHistory = true)]
    public class SplashActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            Android.OS.SystemClock.Sleep(2000);

            // Start our real activity
            StartActivity (typeof (Activity1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'open button'?

Comment: On Droid devices after installing an app you get prompted with a dialog that says the app was successfully installed and it has two buttons, one says open the other says done.  The open is grayed out, or disabled.  That button is not disabled for any other apps I install, just mine.

Answer (score 0):

The intent filter must be as follows, in the main Activity's `<activity>` element:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".<your activity name>"
        android:label="My App" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Hmmm, actually I did try it with both lines but it still was disabled.