# "Open" button disable after installing apk file

Tags: android, apk

I have updated my Android application few days ago (new features).

When debugging with a real device, application starts normally but when I export it with the Export Wizard, [Open] button is unclickable after installation.

Based on the below questions, I have check my manifest file but it seems to be ok :

[why "Open" button after installing apk on android device is disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10995977/why-open-button-after-installing-apk-on-android-device-is-disabled)

[intent-filter in manifest file to enable the open button on install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15394558/intent-filter-in-manifest-file-to-enable-the-open-button-on-install)

Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="xxxxxx"
    android:versionCode="15"
    android:versionName="2.0.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <!-- 課金パーミッション -->
    <permission
        android:name="jp.xxxxx.permissions.xxxx" 
        android:description="@string/billing_permission_title"
        android:label="@string/billing_permission_group_title"
        android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.COST_MONEY"
        android:protectionLevel="dangerous" />

    <!-- ADVS パーミッション -->
    <permission
        android:name="jp.xxxxx.permissions.xxxxx_ADVS"
        android:description="@string/advs_permission_title"
        android:label="@string/advs_permission_group_title" />

    <uses-permission android:name="jp.xxxxx.permissions.xxxxx_BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <!-- Cosmics -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <!-- 通知関係 -->
    <permission
        android:name="jp.xxxxx.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="jp.xxxxx.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <!-- App receives GCM messages. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
        android:vmSafeMode="true" >

        <!-- ■□■□■□ ACTIVITIES ■□■□■□ -->
        <!-- splash -->
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.SplashActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_splash"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

                <data android:scheme="cosmic4test" />
                <data android:host="test.android.sdk.cosmic4.com" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- top activity -->
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>

        <!-- ranking -->
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.RankingFragmentActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>



        <!-- 検索機能 -->
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.SearchActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- LOGIN ACTIVITY -->
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.LoginActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="jp.xxxxx.app.LOGIN_ACTIVITY" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Browserからのアクセス -->

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.fromBrowserActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:label="@string/action_redirect" >
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="xxxxxappli" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>



    ...
     <other activity without intent-filter>
    ...


        <!-- ■□■□■□　SERVICES　■□■□■□ -->


        <!-- 課金サービス（remote） -->
        <service
            android:name=".service.xxxxxInBillService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="jp.xxxxx.permissions.xxxxx_BILLING"
            android:process=":remote" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name=".service.xxxxxInBillInterface.aidl" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <!-- キーワード+カテゴリ情報 -->
        <service android:name=".service.KeywordsAndCategoriesService" />

        <!-- ブロードキャストをハンドリングするサービスを登録 -->
        <service
            android:name=".service.GcmIntentService"
            android:enabled="true" />
        <service
            android:name=".service.xxxxxADVSService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="jp.xxxxx.permissions.xxxxx_ADVS"
            android:process=":remote" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name=".service.xxxxxADVSInterface.aidl" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <!-- ■□■□■□　RECEIVERS ■□■□■□　 -->


        <!-- 端末起動時、アプリ更新をチェック -->
        <receiver android:name=".broadcast.NotificationBroadcast" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!--  -->
        <receiver android:name=".broadcast.AlarmUpdate" />

        <!-- ブロードキャストレシーバー「GCMBroadcastReceiver」を登録 -->
        <receiver
            android:name=".broadcast.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.GCM_RECEIVED_ACTION" />

                <category android:name="jp.xxxxx.service" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- cosmics -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.cosmic4.sdk.android.CM4BroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- 　■□■□■□ META ■□■□■□　 -->

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.crashlytics.ApiKey"
            android:value="xxxxxxxxxxx" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

*(I have cut the activities without intent-filter )*

I am using  2 other projects as Library :

1. android.support.v7
2. google.google_play_services_libproject/google-play-service_lib

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I've solved it in moving [android:scheme] + [android:host] from SplashActivity to the MainActivity.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.SplashActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_splash"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category       android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>     
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:scheme="cosmic4test" />
        <data android:host="test.android.sdk.cosmic4.com" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```